# How can Timer.timeit() takes a negative number as the argument?

Tags: python, timeit

[The `timeit(number=1000000)` method](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) of the `Timer` class in the stdlib's `timeit` module
can take a negative number as its argument, which doesn't make sense to me - what does the result even mean?

Example:

```py
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer('pi * pi', setup='from math import pi')
t.timeit(-30) # <---
```

Comment: it can mean nothing. Maybe author didn't expect that user will use negative value and it doesn't raise error for this value.

Comment: try `print(pi * pi)` and you will get empty screen for `-30`. I think it can repeat code using loop like `for _ in range(-30): ... code ...` and it is correct code (doesn't generate error) but it skips loops

Comment: What would you want it to do if you pass a negative value? Were you hoping for an exception perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source code of `timeit` module:

```
class Timer:
    ...
    def timeit(self, number=default_number):
        ...
        it = itertools.repeat(None, number)
        ...
        try:
            timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
        ...
```

It's not hard to guess that it repeatedly executes code by iterating `itertools.repeat(None, number)`. A simple test will tell what will happen:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> list(repeat(None, -1))
[]
```

So you can know, when number is a negative parameter, it is an empty iterable object, so Timer will not run the code to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

It can mean nothing.

Maybe author didn't expect that user will use negative value and it doesn't raise error for this value.

Try `print(pi * pi)` and you will get empty screen for `-30`.

I think it can repeat code using loop like

```
for _ in range(-30): 
    ... code ...
```

and it is correct code (it doesn't raise error) but it skips loops.

Answer (score 1):

The `number` parameter of `timeit` is implemented using `itertools.repeat` as shown in [Mechanic Pig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73433369).

When a negative count is passed to `repeat`, it is explicitly changed to 0, although this is not documented ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)).

[`itertoolsmodule.c` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/278fdd3e3a2492665b2c2888fd2f428f7f59a3f5/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L4384):

```c
static PyObject *
repeat_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    repeatobject *ro;

    /* [...] */

    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "O|n:repeat", kwargs,
                                     &element, &cnt))
        return NULL;
    /* Does user supply times argument? */
    if (n_args == 2 && cnt < 0)
        cnt = 0;
    
    /* [...] */

    ro->cnt = cnt;
    return (PyObject *)ro;
}
```